# Error localStorage is not defined on refersh (Nuxt Js , Parse server)

Tags: parse-platform, nuxt.js

[image]

Getting the above error on page refresh, but i am not using localStorage in my Code.

Comment: can you share the code that you are using to require and initialize the Parse SDK? Probably you need to verify if the code is running on server side or client side and require the correct package accordingly. Something like this should help: `let Parse; if (window) { Parse = require('parse'); } else { Parse = require('parse/node'); }`

Comment: check `Store.getVehicle`

Answer (score 8):

Perform operations only possible in the browser within the following if statement:

```
if (process.client) {
localStorage...
}
```

See: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/

another option is to only call it in the `beforeMount` or `mounted` functions, since they **always** happen on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

Your app is running on a server so there is no browser or window, which means you do not have access to the APIs provided by the browser.
You can prevent this error by checking if the window object is available before try to access it. for example:

```js
const token = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('token') : null;

//OR

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const token = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('token') : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well What I did was that I created a state like

```js
const thisWindow = useState('thisWindow')
```

and in app.vue onMounted set window like

```js
onMounted( () => {
  thisWindow.value = window
})
```

and just called it in my function and globally

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts to find a solution, I couldn't figure it out. Here's how I managed to use localStorage in Nuxt.js 3 middleware. The code below divides the process into two steps.

Step 1: Assign _token to the state by retrieving the data from localStorage using ref(localStorage.getItem("access_token")). Then, I assign it to a state in the composables/useAuthToken.js folder. It's just a simple piece of code:

```
export const useAuthToken = () => {
    return useState("token", () => null);
};
```

After that get token and set to state useAuthToken

```
const _token = ref(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
const token = useAuthToken(); 
token.value = _token;
```

Step 2: Retrieve the token and use it to make a request for user data. I successfully used the token stored in localStorage. Here's the code for someone who may need to refer to it.

Finally, I separated it into two middlewares and used names to call them.

```
<script setup>

definePageMeta({
     /* middleware/getToken => middleware 1 */
    middleware: [function (to, from) {
        if (process.client) {
            const _token = ref(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
            const token = useAuthToken();
            token.value = _token;
        }
    },
    /* middleware/auth.js => middleware 2 */
    async function (to, from) {
        const { login, me } = useAuth();
        const token = useAuthToken();
        const user = useAuthUser();
        const router = useRouter();

        /* The line of code await me(token.value); is used to send a request to the server to retrieve user data using the token. */

        await me(token.value);
    
        if(!user.value || !user.value.active){
            router.push({ name: "signin" })
        }
    }
],
});
</script>
```

I'm sorry, I don't know English, and I'm trying to translate it for someone who may need it.